# how to troubleshoot intermittent no route to host error

Tags: networking, aix

I have a program that most of the time works, but every now and then it fails with a no route to host error.

The machine is running AIX 5 and has five network interfaces en1, en3, en5, en7 and en10.

Comment: when it happens does it happen consistently for a few seconds, minutes, and then work again? or is it like just a blip and immediately works again.

Comment: @xenoterracide is about few minutes

Comment: (pre I don't know anything about AIX, so this is from a linux perspective )if it connects via dns, do dnsstuff on it make sure that all that is clean (esp glue), do an `mtr` or similar while the problem is occurring to see where packets are going, `tcptraceroute` may also be useful for bypassing a firewall on the right port. I AIX has a routes table you need to go over that thoroughly, and make sure your gateways, and netmasks are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a `traceroute` (different than `tcptraceroute`) when the problem is occurring to determine where the breakage is.  I'm assuming it's close to the AIX box.  Are any neighboring hosts having issues that you know of?  Also, take a look at the ARP cache with something like `arp -an`.  You will have to read the man page on AIX for the right options.  -n turns off DNS resolution and prints IP addresses instead.  Last thing is whether there has been a link loss.  `ifconfig` might tell you whether whether it has a link signal.  Also, any kind of kernel logs might indicate a problem.  Linux has a command `dmesg` to print the Kernel Logs from memory, but AIX probably has something similar.